# Example of a function with specified running time

Tags: algorithms

Can someone help with an example of a function such that $f(m ,n)$:

1. $f(m ,n)$ takes 2 parameters $(m, n); \ m, n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$
2. The optimal running time to compute is $C(|m|^{|n|})$ in the worst case, where $|n|$ and $|m|$ is the size (number of bits) of $n$ and $m$ respectively.
3. The value of $f(m, n)$ is dependent on both $m$ and $n$ such that for two sets: $\{f(1, n_0),f(2, n_0)...f(\infty, n_0)\} = \{f(1, n_1),f(2, n_1)...f(\infty, n_1)\}$ iff $n_0=n_1$
4. The output of the function is polynomial in size as compared to $|m|+|n|$

I have been thinking about it but couldn't find a specific example.

Comment: $m$ and $n$ are integers with 'size' in CS terms i.e. number of bits. Polynomial as compared to the size of or number of bits in $|m|+|n|$

Answer (score 0):

A plausible candidate is

$$f(m,n)=(m,n,H(m,|m|^{|n|}),H(n,|m|^{|n|})),$$

where $H(t,k)=1$ if the Turing machine denoted by $t$ halts in at most $k$ steps, or $H(t,k)=0$ otherwise.  I have no proof that the optimal running time is as claimed, but I suspect that it does, and all other criteria are met.

Comment: thank you. So the way I understand the idea is a sort of restricted halting problem where one of the integer ($m$) is a TM description and $|m|^{|n|}$ is the number of steps. So in the worst case we would have to run it for $|m|^{|n|}$ steps before providing an answer if it halts. is this correct? A few doubts though: 1. Not every integer would be a valid TM, so in that case we output 0. it that fine? 2. When we say $m$ is a TM what is the input to it that you are proposing: is it $n$? 3. You provided 2 such $H()$, this confused me. why do we need 2?

Comment: 4. and the last caveat you added: "I have no proof..." - why wouldn't this hold. I mean we are dealing with the halting problem in a restricted sense. So isn't there a proof (would be surprising) on the restricted case of halting problem for this statement: "There can't be a generic/universal Algo to decide if TM machine halts in X steps without running it for X steps"  (has been ages so I ashamedly do not remember )